# Convert Bounding Box format to YOLO style by looping through text files

Tags: python, loops, yolo, bounding-box

I am trying to convert my bounding boxes in anno.txt files to Yolo-readable format.

The bbox coordinates are currently in the format (min x, min y, max x, max y) or (left, top, bottom, right) and should be converted to YOLO style, i.e. (x_center, y_center, width, height).

Each text file looks like this, with a varying number of rows. Some files are empty:

```
<sample_ID>_anno.txt
Class A     0.288571    0.980469    0.301786    1.000000
Class B     0.371786    0.000000    0.482143    0.176758
```

My idea is to loop through the text files, (load into dataframe), convert the coordinates and save them in a different directory.

However, I'm not sure how to facilitate this. How could I implement this in python?

**Edit**
I figured out by modifying the code from this tutorial https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/object-detection-with-yolov7-a74fa1f03c7e.

My soln might not be the most elegant but works

```py
import os
import pybboxes as pbx

def to_yolo_bbox(bbox, image_size):
    yolo_box = pbx.convert_bbox(bbox, from_type='albumentations',  to_type='yolo', image_size=image_size)
    yolo_box = list(yolo_box)
    output_bb = [round(elem, 6) for elem in yolo_box]
    return output_bb


img_folder = 'Projects/Data/all_images'
label_folder = 'Projects/Data/bounding_boxes'

_, _, files = next(os.walk(img_folder))
pos = 0
for f in files:
    source_img = os.path.join(img_folder, f)
    if pos < 12166:
        dest_folder = 'yolov7/train'
    elif (pos >= 12166 and pos < 16220):
        dest_folder = 'yolov7/val'
    else:
        dest_folder = 'yolov7/test'

    destination_img = os.path.join(dest_folder,'images', f)

    # shutil.copy(source_img, destination_img) ## Uncomment for copying images
    # check for corresponding label
    label_file_basename = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
    label_source_file = f'{label_file_basename}_anno.txt'
    label_dest_file = f'{label_file_basename}.txt'
    
    label_source_path = os.path.join(label_folder, label_source_file)
    label_dest_path = os.path.join(dest_folder, 'labels', label_dest_file)
    print(label_dest_path)
    # if file exists, copy it to target folder
    if os.path.exists(label_source_path):
        # parse the content of the txt file
        result = []
        with open(label_source_path, 'r') as file:
            # Step 2: Read the content of the file into a variable
            line_number = 1
            for line in file.readlines():
                line_list = line.split()
                label = line_list[0]
                line_list.pop(0)

                l = []
                for t in line_list:
                    try:
                        l.append(float(t.replace(',','.'))) # Some coordinates use , instead of . 
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
                try:
                    l = to_yolo_bbox(l, (2800, 1024))
                except TypeError:
                    pass

                l = ['{:.6f}'.format(x) for x in l]
                l.insert(0, label)
                bbox_string = '\t'.join(l)
                result.append(bbox_string)
            if result:
                with open(label_dest_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    f.write('\n'.join(result))
        pos += 1
```